# Polymer cross browser events

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Am I reading this right? If Shady DOM doesn't have event retargeting, does this mean if you need retargeting, and you support any browsers that don't have ShadowDOM (aka iPhones), you'll always have to do it manually? https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#retargeting

The problem I'm trying to solve is event communication between Polymer customer elements. I want some elements to be consumers of events, and others to be producers. However, browsers such as Safari are on our supported list, which I believe means they'll be using shady DOM.

So a code example, would go something like this:

```
<wut-action async remote="false" file="/actions/saveInventory.js">
  <wut-button class="saveInventory">
  </wut-button>
</wut-action>
```

I want to create a `<wut-button>` custom element that produces a `doAction` event on tap. And I want `<wut-action>` to consume the `doAction` event (listener). I assume because of bubbling, I'll need to do the composition as shown above.

I'm concerned after reading the docs that this design won't work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, listening to events from distributed children is supported in both Shady and Shadow DOM. Your design would work across browsers. I verified this on Chrome 54, Firefox 49, and Safari 10.

Assuming `wut-button` fires an event named "x-event", `wut-action` could [listen](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#event-listeners) to that event like this:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'wut-action',
  listeners: {
    'x-event': '_onEvent'
  },
  _onEvent: function(e) {
    console.log('event', e.detail);
  }
});
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JbPOZd?editors=1011)